# Angular swiper gives error when compiling error TS2430: Interface 'SwiperContainerEventMap' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLElementEventMap'

Tags: angular, swiper.js

1. I want to use swiper version 9.3.0 for angular version 15.2.8 and install swiper using `npm i swiper`
2. As per the guide of new swiper elements web-components I follow this guide to register swiper with angular.

```html
// import function to register Swiper custom elements
import { register } from 'swiper/element/bundle';
// register Swiper custom elements
register();
```

Then, I am running angular command `ng serve -o` but compilation failed and gives error like below

```html
error TS2430: Interface 'SwiperContainerEventMap' incorrectly extends interface 'HTMLElementEventMap'. 
  Types of property '"click"' are incompatible.
    Type 'CustomEvent<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 20 more.

6 interface SwiperContainerEventMap extends HTMLElementEventMap {
```

I have added schemas inside app.module.ts file too.

```html
@NgModule({
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
```

Here is [official guide](https://swiperjs.com/element)

How to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I guess swiperjs 9.3.0 make a mistakes.
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6657

I set lower version :  "swiper": "9.2.4" 
until they fix it.

Comment: @BYUNGJUJIN Yes. Now it is working with swiper version 9.2.4

Comment: @BYUNGJUJIN They update new release with solution of this error in `"swiper": "^9.3.1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue.
According to github swiper issues (https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/6657) it us caused due to the combination of the latest versions of Angular, Typescript and swiper.

We managed to solve this by downgrading our package.json.

```js
{
  "name": "swiperjs-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/core": "4.7.3",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "4.1.0",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "4.1.1",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "4.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.0.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "swiper": "^9.2.2",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "4.7.3",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.8.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Hopefully this will help you

Comment: @BYUNGJUJIN Yes. Now it is working with swiper version 9.2.4 Until they fixed the issue in swiper version 9.3.0

Comment: They update new release with solution of this error in `"swiper": "^9.3.1"`